# SqlQuery returns no results but ScanQuery contains result

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ignite

The cache in Ignite contains the following data:

```
+=======================================================================================================================================================+
|   Key Class    | Key |           Value Class           |                          Value                                                               |
+=======================================================================================================================================================+
| java.lang.Long | 1   | o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl | com.test.domain.Domain [hash=-533910214, Domain=x.blub.com, id=1, advId=31]               |
| java.lang.Long | 2   | o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl | com.test.domain.Domain [hash=-482120537, Domain=x.blub.de, id=2, advId=31]                |
| java.lang.Long | 3   | o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl | com.test.domain.Domain [hash=-1060766828, Domain=x.blub.at, id=3, advId=31]               |
| java.lang.Long | 4   | o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl | com.test.domain.Domain [hash=376860969, Domain=y.blab.com, id=4, advId=94]                |
| java.lang.Long | 5   | o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl | com.test.domain.Domain [hash=1641697092, Domain=y.blib.com, id=5, advId=94]               |
| java.lang.Long | 6   | o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl | com.test.domain.Domain [hash=-757055874, Domain=z.bla.com, id=6, advId=1]                  |
| java.lang.Long | 7   | o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl | com.test.domain.Domain [hash=-1536137434, Domain=h.bla.com, id=7, advId=20]                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In my spring-boot project I do the following query:

```
SqlQuery<Long, Domain> domainSqlQuery = new SqlQuery<>(Domain.class, "advId = ?");
trackdomainSqlQuery.setArgs(31);
List<Cache.Entry<Long, Domain>> domainCacheEntrySqlQueryResults = domainConfigurationCache.query(domainSqlQuery).getAll();
```

the query returns an empty list, but if I run a `ScanQuery` I get them all

```
List<Cache.Entry<Long, Domain>> domainCacheEntryScanQueryResults = domainConfigurationCache.query(new ScanQuery()).getAll();
```

Here the result from the `ScanQuery`:

```
[IgniteBiTuple [val1=1, val2=Domain{id=1, domain='blib.blub.com', advId=31}], 
 IgniteBiTuple [val1=2, val2=Domain{id=2, domain='blib.blub.de', advId=31}], 
 IgniteBiTuple [val1=3, val2=Domain{id=3, domain='Domain=blib.blub.at', advId=31}], 
 IgniteBiTuple [val1=4, val2=Domain{id=4, domain='blab.blab.com', advId=94}], 
 IgniteBiTuple [val1=5, val2=Domain{id=5, domain='blib.blab.com', advId=94}], 
 IgniteBiTuple [val1=6, val2=Domain{id=6, domain='blo.bla.com', advId=1}], 
 IgniteBiTuple [val1=7, val2=Domain{id=7, domain='blu.bla.com', advId=20}]]
```

Also just for the info the *version* I'm using for `ignite-core` and `ignite-indexing` is **2.6.0**

Anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How is the cache created? Do you really have row for advId?

Comment: @alamar the cache is created somewhere else, but regardless when I connect to visor and run cache -scan on the cache I see all the results. So yeah it sure is there

Comment: Having cache does not mean that you have SQL table and SQL rows for desired fields.

Comment: @alamar actually your hint helped me somehow. It seems we have a _QueryEntity Based Configuration_ and in there the package name was `com.test.domain.cache.Domain` which we changed to `com.test.domain.Domain` so although it was writing with the correct package name in the cache the schema was different. I guess that raises another question on if it is possible to migrate the data that already is collected to the new package name.

Comment: I guess you will have to fetch objects from cache `withKeepBinary()`, recreate objects from BinaryObject fields and put them back then delete legacy objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have indicated:

Ignite will only index cache entries where key and value types match what your tables expect.
You can store any types in cache but table will only accept single key type and single value type. You can also have multiple tables per cache, btw, provided their types do not overlap.

Entries whose types did not match any table will be present in cache but not obtainable via SQL. This is what you observed when package name was `com.test.domain.cache.Domain` in configuration but `com.test.domain.Domain` in practice (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your second line:

```
trackdomainSqlQuery.setArgs(31L);
```

Your key class is a long but you're passing in an integer. (I've not seen this in Java but I had the same problem using the Python API.)